# Parking domain over another domain which you do not own!

Tags: domain-parking

Is it possible to park domain yyy.com over, say youtube.com (which I do not own)?

Youtube.com is filtered in my country and I wondering is it possible to register domain yyy.com and park it over youtube.com? I know this should be done using Youtube Administrator, But I am wondering is there a trick to do this myself? For example by using a NameServer special kind Record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's unlikely to work because what likely is filtered is the IP address (try accessing http://66.102.13.91) and not (only) the domain name.

Unfortunately, most censors are not stupid. Depending on where you live, they are also humorless, which can land you in any kind of nasty trouble.

Answer (score 0):

You will be creating a CName to youtube. It doesn't work because that way it defaults to google.com

If you can afford it buy cheap hosting and use that as a reverse proxy, if thats legal.